# When does View obtain it's bounds?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, bounds, activity-lifecycle

I have a main `Activity` with `TextView` on it. I need perform some actions at application startup. These actions use `TextView`'s bounds.

I tryed override `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods, but `TextView`'s bound are always (0,0).

How can I capture a moment when `TextView` obtains it's size?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`onWindowFocusChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29) and see if it helps:

> This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the
>   user. The default implementation clears the key tracking state, so
>   should always be called.

This is written about [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29):

> Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your
>   activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard
>   may be in front. Use onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) to know for certain
>   that your activity is visible to the user (for example, to resume a
>   game).

Answer (score 0):

The moment you are looking for is onMeasure().